# Вывести без квадратных скобок и кавычек

Tags: python

Я хочу чтобы конечный результат появлялся без квадратных скобок и кавычек

```
favorite_places = {
    'alex': ['usa', 'italy', 'korea'],
    'monroe': ['canada', 'france'],
    'sasha': ['japan'],
}
for name, place in favorite_places.items():
    print(f"{place}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так:)

P.S: [:-2] Это удаляет последние 2 буквы стринга, если будет [:-1] то только последнтю букву

```
favorite_places = {
    'alex': ['usa', 'italy', 'korea'],
    'monroe': ['canada', 'france'],
    'sasha': ['japan'],
}
result = "";
for name in favorite_places :
    for place in favorite_places[name] :
        result = result + place + ", "


print(result[:-2])
```

Comment: не, мне нужно чтоб появлялся список в строчку с запятыми

Comment: изменил, надеюсь помог вам)

Comment: я ошибся в строчку выводить не надо, а так ваш код выводится в столбик и без скобок и запятых, так что спасибо

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> print(f"{place}")
> ```

```
print(", ".join(place))
```

Comment: join() еще не было по программе

Comment: Значит циклом выводи.